# Colors red in external monitors - Ubuntu 22

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, external-display, xrandr

I have a Lenovo extreme gen3 with ubuntu 22 installed. I have an external monitor at home where the colors are perfect.

The weird problem is that all the external monitors other than my one at home, don't work. I see all the colors red.

I've tried different monitors (also one of the same model as the one I have at home!), different cables, different types of cables (VGA HDMI thunderbolt)... nothing to do. The colors are reddish.

I've tried with `xrandr --gamma 1:1:1` but nothing to do, if I change the Green and Blue value I see colors changing... but not with the first red value.

Do you have any suggestions?